# SonataAdminBundle error" Call to a member function get() on null "when override controller

Tags: sonata, symfony-3.4

I wish override controller in Sonata Admin, but it returns:

> Call to a member function get() on null

Code in services.yml:

```
app.admin.model:
class: AppBundle\Admin\ModelAdmin
tags:
    - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Model,label: Model  }
arguments:
    - null
    - AppBundle\Entity\Model
    - AppBundle\Controller\ModelController
public: true
```

Code in controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ModelController extends Controller {

    /**
     * 
     * @param int|string|null $id
     * 
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException
     * 
     * @return Response
     */
    public function showAction($id = null) {

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $id = $request->get($this->admin->getIdParameter());

        $object = $this->admin->getObject($id);

        if (!$object) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(sprintf('unable to find the object with id : %s', $id));
        }

        $this->admin->checkAccess('show', $object);

        $preResponse = $this->preShow($request, $object);
        if (null !== $preResponse) {
            return $preResponse;
        }

        $this->admin->setSubject($object);

        return $this->render($this->admin->getTemplate('show'), array(
                    'action' => 'show',
                    'object' => $object,
                    'elements' => $this->admin->getShow(),
                        ), null);
    }
}
```

It's a simple copy/paste of vendor for the moment, and when I return in ma view, I get this error:

```
CRITICAL
16:31:37
php Call to a member function get() on null
CRITICAL
16:31:37
request Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Call to a member function get() on null" at /var/www/html/acianovintra2/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Controller/CRUDController.php line 988
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Is your `services.yml` looks exactly like the snippet you copy/paste in this issue ? If yes, it has not a valid indent.

Comment: No, my indent is correct.

Comment: It works when the Sonata controller is put in argument